# Vba code for adding multiple comments for a range of cells in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub codingcheck()
Dim x As Range
For Each x In Worksheets("Verbatims").Range("N2:AB500")
For Each y In Worksheets("Coding sheet").Range("E2:E500")
Z = Worksheets("Coding sheet").Range("B2:B500")
If x = y Then
Range("N2:AB500").Value.AddComment
Range("N2:AB500").Value.Comment.Visible = False
Range("N2:AB500").Value.Comment.Text (Z)
 End If
Next j
Next i
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I have a range of cells which need to added with multiple comments but if my code where in the line `Range("N2:AB500").Value.AddComment` is not accepting but it is accepting as `Range("N2").Value.AddComment`

Comment: Try to loop each cell in your range, adding the comment. Something like `For each Cell in Range("YourRange")`

Comment: if you look at my code, i have mentioned in the third & fourth line as x, y but when i mention it in the code as x.Value.AddComment instead of Range("N2:AB500").Value.AddComment i'm getting a compile error @Foxfire And Burns And Burns